# Loading local json file and assigning the result to a variable

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, getjson

i'm having problem with paresing a json file, i don't now where is the problem, hope you help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d;
$.getJSON("empl-estab.json", function (data) {
d=data;
});
console.log(d);
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
                        text: 'Statistiques'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Plan'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: d.categories,
                    },
                    series: [{
                            type: 'column',
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            data: d.data,
                            showInLegend: false
                        }]

                });
</script>
```

> the error is : d is undefined

Comment: All code dependent on `d` must be inside your `.getJSON` success function. You know... where `d=data` is. So... yes, you'll need to throw your HighCharts in there too.

Comment: I solve it, like @Mamun said, i should move all the code to the $.getJSON, and i ve had a problem of file location, thank you guys, you all awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all the code related to the `response` result inside `getJSON`'s `callback` function. This is happening because all the code outside are executing before the request is complete. Hence `d` is undefined.

```
var d;
$.getJSON("empl-estab.json", function (data) {
  d=data;
  console.log(d);
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
        text: 'Statistiques'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Plan'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: d.categories,
    },
    series: [{
            type: 'column',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: d.data,
            showInLegend: false
        }]

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of the GET request.  The code you've written executed the `console.log` statement before the GET request returns.  You want to place your logic in the callback function that executes after the document is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Also, inside an `async function` the variable can wait for the download without problems:

```
async function load() {
    //The await keyword will make the d variable wait for the json file
    var d = await fetch('empl-estab.json').then(file => file.json());

    //Now your d variable is avaliable
    console.log(d);    
}
load();
```